# Unable to Copy or Cut MTS Files

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mts

I have a set of MTS files from Panasonic GH3 DSLR, cut and pasted from my SD card to my external HD (WD My Passport). While some of them can be cut (or copied) over to another harddrive (same - WD My Passport) - others cannot be. I keep getting an error after the 12-15mins into the copy attempt. The error dialog box says: 
Sometimes the file just takes very very long to be copied, with the 
"X MB of Y MB" indicator not moving at all.

I am using a Mac OS X 10.8.5 to do the copy.
The mts file *can* be played and smoothly with VLC player. ANd nowhere in the movie can I find a sign of the file being corrupt. Note also, it is only 1 or 2 of the mts files which keep on having this error, whereas the others in the same folder can be copied.

I have tried to cut the file, copy it, or even using a image cloning device to (CCCloner). I am still havinga problem.

What can be the reason for this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Hey there humanitiesclinic :)

Do you have any read/write protecting options enabled on your camera? This may be preventing the files from being altered or copied (due to copyright purposes) from the card.

Have you tried doing this on another external drive or directly onto your computer? Have you tried using another computer and see if that works? Have you encountered other problems with the WD My Passport drive?

I'd recommend running [WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=1T9fVN) tool to see if the drive passes both the quick and the extended tests so you can safely exclude it as the potential cause of the problem.

Does the SD card have any writing or access permissions enabled (software or hardware)? What's the model of the card?

Captain_WD.

Comment: Hi Captain_WD. I am not sure if it is a drive problem. Because as I said, similar files that were from the camera and on my WD My Passport drive could be copied to my 2nd external drive. I will try copying the strange file to my computer now.

Comment: How did it go? Any progress? Is the drive at full health? 
Post some feedback on how the situation is developing, you may help other people with the same issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post  correctly, you are unable to make a copy of your SD card because the bad file halts the copy process?

Since you are unable to make a protection copy of the card before making changes, I would be reluctant to do any modifications as that might have more consequences and you don't have a back-up copy.

I would use ClipWrap to convert the files from the card  to ProRes ClipWrap will do each file individually, so if one is corrupt it can be safely bypassed.
ClipWrap costs around US$50, they have a trial period that will transfer the first minute only of each file so you can test it out.

http://www.divergentmedia.com/clipwrap

If you are able to make a protection copy of the card, then many cameras have a card structure restore feature (not formatting) called database restore or something like that in their menu. You might check your manual and see if you have that feature.